# Stop carousel on menu click

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap "hamburger" menu and a Bootstrap carousel. The carousel sliding is very distracting once the user clicks the "hamburger" menu allowing a list to pop downward.

I know that `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false data-ride="carousel">` would stop the carousel. I am trying to accomplish this when the user clicks on the "hamburger" menu.

I was thinking that I need a jQuery `click()` function to execute when the "hamburger menu" is clicked like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar-toggle collapsed").click(function(){
        alert("Clicked.");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


 <nav class="navbar" id="skew">
      <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-2">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar" id="slider-nav"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar" id="slider-nav"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar" id="slider-nav"></span>
      </button>
    </div>    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="second-navbar">
        <li><a href="/about/">ABOUT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </nav>


</body>
</html>
```

However, this clicking is not working as I am not receiving an alert message. I am new to jQuery so I am not understanding what is incorrect.

Here I can stop the carousel when the page is loaded:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#myCarousel').carousel({
         pause: true,
            interval: false
      });

});
</script>
```

Any suggestions as how I should combine the clicking and stopping to stop the carousel when the "hamburger" menu is clicked are appreciated.

--UPDATE:---
Typing the whole class with no spaces allowed for the following and it worked:

```
$(".navbar-toggle.collapsed").click(function(){
    alert("Clicked.");
});
```

Now, per my original question, I am attempting to stop the carousel from sliding when the user clicks the hamburger menu button.

I was thinking something like this:

```
$(".navbar-toggle.collapsed").click(function(){
    alert("Clicked.");
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
         pause: true,
            interval: false
      });
});
```

which appears incorrect. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you're selecting what you think you're selecting with: `$(".navbar-toggle collapsed")`

Comment: You're update might not be working because I don't see in the HTML that you posted any element with `id="myCarousel"`

Comment: @Adjit I did not include the carousel code for simplicity sake. I have a carousel with that id in my code; double checked. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right back to the beginning what you are first doing is selecting the element and adding on the click method here. The document.ready part is just a wait for the page to finish loading. 
Putting them together .navbar-toggle.collapsed is waiting adding the click to the element when collapsed.

So now we have done that, we need to play with the carousel and get it to stop.
So lets look at the docs.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

We have a function `.carousel('pause')` that we can use.
From the looks of things you have to start it as well. So hence `$('#myCarousel').carousel()`

and the finished product ....

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#myCarousel').carousel();

    $(".navbar-toggle.collapsed").click(function(){
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
    });
});
```

I hope that helps and gets you started with jquery - which fyi that and bootstrap are excellent tools to have on your side.

Comment: Thank you for your polite and detailed answer. I did get it working. I look forward to continuing on with jQuery. The carousel link you provided is very helpful.

Comment: No props, it's nice to be nice and helping people like yourself on the first steps with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a '.' from the `collapsed` selector so JQuery knows its a class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar-toggle.collapsed").click(function(){
        alert("Clicked.");
    });
});
```

Comment: I added the class selector, but when I click on the menu to expand it, I receive no alert message.

Comment: Try `$(".navbar-toggle.collapsed")`. Note the space is removed because the classes are on the same element.

Comment: Your suggestion about moving the class selector worked. Thank you. That was part one of the question, however. Please see the update.

Comment: @SamSmith just add your carousel snippet to where you have the alert. And then you can also run an if statement to determine whether to pause or start the carousel

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something closer to:

```
$(".navbar-toggle.collapsed").click(function(){
    alert("Clicked.");
});
```

`.navbar-toggle.collapsed` Will select any element with both the "navbar-toggle" and "collapsed" classes (Assuming that the button has the `.collapsed` class at the time of clicking)

Comment: I added the class selector and removed the document ready function, but when I click on the menu to expand it, I receive no alert message. And oh... the button has a `navbar-collapse collapse in` at clicking time, so I must adjust that.

Comment: @SamSmith Can you double check that the `.collapsed` class is present before the element is clicked? If not, just remove the `.collapsed` completely and see if that works.

Answer (score -1):

OMG! That's quiet easy. Just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navbar-toggle.collapsed").click(function(){
        $("script").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: It removes any script, what moves the carousel.

Comment: This solution does not work for me as the carousel still slides upon the menu click.